# Straight Thread Seal Performance

Tags: temperature, fasteners, bolting, threads, seals

Is it possible for straight threads to create a hydraulic/mechanical seal **without** the use of o-rings or sealants? From what I've read, in the oil industry buttress threads are used, in my application I need moderate tensile strength, preferably overkill though, and it needs to be able to seal without o-rings or sealant as it's extremely high temperature.

Previously, tapered threads have failed due to hoop stress and it is not possible to reinforce the walls so straight threads need to be used. Multi-start threads are also a possibility. The pressure it needs to hold is also very low no more than 30PSI.
Any advice and links to information is welcomed. :)

Comment: A multi-start thread is even worse since it provides multiple spiral leak paths rather than just one. Isn't the solution for something stronger to use larger dimensioned tapered threads? If the pressure is very low then what is causing all the hoop stress? You said no sealants, but does indium and indium solders count as a sealant? They are rather low temperature far as metals are concerned but higher than O-rings. Unsure if it is feasible to use fine indium wire to wrap around the threads for direct use as a sealant similar to tape.

Comment: If temperature is what ails you, and you have a preference for overkill, consider a metal gasket.

Comment: I would prefer a metal-on metal seal before the threads. Like a union.  depending on what the parts are made out of the "gasket" can be part of one of the parts. Example: https://www.mcmaster.com/products/unions/high-pressure-socket-connect-stainless-steel-unthreaded-pipe-fittings/